# Rails: handling object creation via candidate key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table `foo` which `belongs_to :bar` (`bar` `has_many :foos`).

There are too many `foos` for it to be sensible to offer the user a list when they're creating a `bar`, so I'm going to get the user to enter the name of the `bar` that the `foo` belongs to. The name is a candidate key -- guaranteed to be present and unique.

I think I can see the steps I need to take: make `foo` validate that `bar_id` is present, and somewhere put a `find_where` to look up the `bar` that has the given name (if it's not present I'll get a `nil`, so the validation should fail -- good).

What I want to know is where's the best place to put that `find_where` in order to check all creations and edits of `foo` whilst maintaining DRY principles? How to I join it up to the new and edit forms? (Or is there a more Rails way?)

Rails 4, by the way.

EDIT:

To make it more concrete, suppose I have a list of every airport in the world, in `Airport`, which contains the airport name (`name`), the 3-character identifier that gets put on your luggage tag (`code`), and the Rails-generated `airport_id`. And suppose I have `Departure` which `belongs_to :airport`. When I create/edit a `departure`, the user enters the airport `code`, which I have to map to an actual entry in `Airport` to create/edit the entry. What's the best place/way to do that?

Comment: i think you should not use `foo` or `bar` in your question and convert them to more sensible example... " the number of `foo`s and `bar`s in this question is too damn high"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to do all of that, Rails has a way! When you specify an association between two models in your database, it suffices to simply add the dependent model name to a validation:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar, validate: true
end
```

This will cause ActiveRecord to validate the presence of the `bar` object in question. And, because this is Rails, there are other ways of writing this type of validation:

With [`validates_associated`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
  validates_associated :bar
 end
```

or with [`validates presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar, inverse_of :foo
  validates :bar, presence: true
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo, inverse_of :bar
end
```

Beware a couple gotchas:

- In the `validates_associated` construction, you must make sure to only specify the validation on one of your two related models. If you specify the `validates_associated` attribute on both, your validations will call each other infinitely.
- In the `validates presence` version, you must specify the `inverse_of` relationship in order to validate the presence of the associated AR model.

**EDIT**

In response to your edited question, I've updated my answer:

You'll want to query the `Airport` by its `code` attribute in your `DeparturesController`, under the `#create` and `#update` actions:

```
 class DeparturesController < ApplicationController 

   def create
     airport = Airport.find_by(code: params[:departure][:code])
     if airport
       departure = airport.departures.build(params[:departure])
       if departure.save
         ...
       else
         ...
       end
     else 
       ...
     end
   end
 end
```

The upshot of using the `find_by` method in ActiveRecord is that it returns `nil` if the search fails, making it easy for you to write error-handling logic in the event that your user enters an invalid code.

Comment: Thanks, that simplifies the validation. That still leaves the question of the best way/place to handle the lookup of the `bar` based on the user entry of a candidate key.

Comment: @digitig I'm a little confused, what are you trying to check exactly?

Comment: You've already helped with the checking bit. My main concern was with the mechanics of creation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd like to help you with the rest of your question but I'm still unclear as to what you are asking. What aspect of the creation mechanics do you wish to know regarding `find_where`?

Comment: Sorry, I caught the return key before I could explain properly. I've edited the original question.

Comment: @digitig I've edited my answer, hope it explains what you wanted to know

Comment: Thanks again. I thought I'd read that `find_by_x` was (mildly) deprecated? I'll go for it anyway.

Comment: @digitig I wasn't aware that they were *mildly* deprecated but that is what the edge docs say. They recommend using `Model.find_by(attr: value)`, which works just as well. I've edited my answer to use the non-deprecated `find_by` method

Comment: Yes, gives me the bones of what I need to do, and works nicely. Thanks.

There's still quite a bit of plumbing to do, particularly for editing an existing record (populate the code field on the form, and then if the user changes the airport I have to work out how to delete it from one airport and add it to another, but that looks like normal coding (unless there are some rails tricks I should know about).

One thing puzzling is how to notify an invalid code. I know how to redirect to another page with an error flash, but I don't know how to reload the current (form) page with an error flash.